# Que veut dire « on équit » ?

Tags: expressions

En regardant un film, il me semble avoir croisé l'expression « on équit » dont je n'ai aucune idée du sens. Du côté prononciation, j'en suis cent pour cent sûr. Comme Google ne me retourne rien sur cette phrase, je crois avoir fait une faute d'orthographe. 
J'aimerais aussi savoir l'équivalent en anglais aussi s'il existe.

Une petite précision : dans cette scène, un gars a rendu un service à son pote et avant de partir il lui dit « maintenant on équit ». Son pote lui répond « on équit mon poteau ».

Comment: *On est quitte*.

Comment: Note à propos du son « é » que tu as entendu, c'est à cause de la liaison du « on » et du « est » qui forme « _nest_ » souvent prononcé « né » (son nasal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

« On est [quitte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quitte) », ou en français soutenu « nous sommes quittes ». Cela signifie qu'il n'y a plus de dette entre les deux personnes, vraisemblablement parce que l'une a rendu un service à l'autre dans le passé et l'autre vient de lui rendre un service qui compense.

Je soupçonne que le dialogue est

> — On est quitte ? [avec un ton montant : question, en langage familier parlé]
>   — On est quitte, mon pote.

avec un e muet (schwa) un peu prononcé.

Comment: Ouais, là ça fait du sens. Merci (:

Answer (score 4):

Gilles gave you the proper spelling in French, « On est quitte » and explains the meaning in French very well.

In English, this would be:

> We are even.

Since you asked for the English equivalent, here you go.

Answer (score 1):

Et pour préciser, mon "poto", c'est le terme familier actuel pour "pote", lui même argot de "copain".

It's like "buddy" in english/american.

Comment: Oui. Tu pourrais aussi définir «poteau» puisque l'OP l'a utilisé.